# Eclipse Luna : Tool to Create new MySQL database

Tags: database, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I already know how to create new databases using MySQL command line .

`Is there a tool provided by Eclipse Luna for creating MySQL databases ?`

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a tool, when it's this simple to create a database and tables with a Java application?

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateDatabase implements Runnable {

    private Connection connection;

    private Statement statement;

    private String databaseAddress;
    private String logon;
    private String password;

    public CreateDatabase(String logon, String password) {
        this.logon = logon;
        this.password = password;
        this.databaseAddress = "localhost:3306";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            connect();
            createDatabase();
//          dropTable("user_account");
            createUserAccountTable();
            commit();
            disconnect();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + databaseAddress + "/?" + "user=" + logon + "&password="
                + password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    }

    private void createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "create database if not exists accounts";
        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
        sql = "use accounts";
        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
        sql = "set names 'utf8'";
        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
    }

    private void createUserAccountTable() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "create table if not exists user_account ( " +
                "user_account_number integer not null auto_increment, " +
                "user_account_name varchar(40) not null, " +
                "created_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp, " +
                "last_used_timestamp timestamp not null, " +
                "primary key (user_account_number)) " +
                "engine=InnoDB, " +
                "character set=utf8, " +
                "auto_increment=10000000 ";

        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
    }

    void dropTable(String tableName) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "drop table if exists " + tableName;
        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
    }

    private void commit() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "commit";
        statement.execute(sql);
        displayUpdateCount(sql);
    }

    private void displayUpdateCount(String sql) throws SQLException {
        int count = statement.getUpdateCount();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Executing SQL \"");

        if (sql.length() > 40) builder.append(sql.substring(0, 40));
        else builder.append(sql);

        builder.append("\" resulted in ");
        builder.append(count);
        builder.append(" row");
        if (count != 1) builder.append("s");
        builder.append(" changed");

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }

    private void disconnect() throws SQLException {
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            String s = "The logon and password for the database " +
                    "must be provided.";
            System.err.println(s);
        } else {
            new CreateDatabase(args[0], args[1]).run();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: nice solution , Thanks !! But I still want to know if there is a tool or plugin for creating MySQL database in eclipse ??

Comment: @JamesDaniel: I use [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) for general database functions.  It's separate from Eclipse.  But as far as data definition for a database, I prefer creating a Java application that I can run against the MySQL database on the web server.